# Open other installed apps from within my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, function, embed

I am looking for a way to call other installed applications from within my app. For example: Can a user open his Skype app from my app?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`-openURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a) and [`-canOpenURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a).

The application in question must register [`CFBundleURLTypes`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToRegisterURLHandler) for it to respond to the aforementioned open method. In the case of Skype, for example, the URL protocol is `skype:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)openAppUsingPrivateAPI:(NSString *)bundleId {
    Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    NSObject * workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
    BOOL isopen = [workspace performSelector:@selector(openApplicationWithBundleID:) withObject:bundleId];

}
```

use private method to do it